# R Error "attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex"

Tags: r

This code doesn't work in R 4.0.3

```
library(foreach)  #Version: 1.5.1
library(doSNOW)   #Version: 1.0.19
library(parallel) #Version: 4.0.3

cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

info <- NULL
tm <- snow.time(
  info <- foreach(x = 1:8, .combine = rbind) %dopar% x
)

stopCluster(cl)

print(tm)
plot(tm)
```

Error in data$data[[rank]] <- d :
attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

p.s. This code working in R version 3.3.2

Comment: I haven't tested this but basic question are all the packages updated to their latest versions? (Often the solution after updating R)

Comment: "Clean" install, all packages are latest